# Sending request to a post controller function from another controller function

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I have a controller like this.

```
public function barcode_approve(Request $request)
{
    $barcodes = $request->input('barcode_values');
    $upload_ids = $request->input('upload_id');
    ....
}
```

It is defined as post in route without any problem.

```
Route::post('my/url','BarcodeScanController@barcode_approve');
```

I would like to use barcode_approve by sending request from controller like

```
public function push_approve(){

    $request = ['barcode_values' => '23ssdwe','upload_id'=>234234];

    $this->barcode_approve($request);
    .....

}
```

But *$reqeust->input* doesn't give the value when I send it through controller function (push_approve)

How can I send values from another controller function as input in $request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Required argument in barcode_approve() method must be `instance of Request`, not just array even if u call it `$request`.
So if you realy need your code to work, you must create Request instance at your push_approve method()

```
$request = new Request(['barcode_values' => '23ssdwe','upload_id'=>234234]);
```

But better way will be to route Request to push_approve() initially

Answer (score 1):

Your barcode_approve expects a Request object, not an array.  While you could instantiate a new Request object and potentially inject your fake inputs, I would consider that a bad practice.

Whenever you find yourself trying to call a controller method from another controller method, it usually means you have logic that can be extracted, either to a model, a trait, or in the case of the same controller, a separate protected function.

The purpose of a controller is to be the transport method, you shouldn't have much business logic in it, extract logic to the models when you can.

Answer (score 0):

`extends` your controller with the controller you want to used 
then call the function `this->barcode_approve($request)`